Proof that the supremum of a continuous function is part of the range of that function
I'm following the textbook "Calculus" By Spivak. Currently, I'm reading a proof given for the following theorem:
"If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then there exists an $x^*\in[a,b]$ such that $\forall x\in [a,b] f(x^*)\geq f(x)$."
However, I found the proof given in the textbook to be unintuitive and I've devised my own proof, which I wanted to confirm. For context, the following theorems are already proven:
"If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a) < k$ and $f(b) > k$, $\exists x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x) = k$" - $\textbf{Theorem 1}$
"If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it is also bounded above on $[a,b]$" - $\textbf{Theorem 2}$
"If a non-empty set of real numbers has an upper bound, it has a supremum" - $\textbf{Theorem 3}$
I'll also be using this lemma:
"If $a > b$, there exists a $c > 0$ such that $a - c > b$" - $\textbf{Lemma 1}$
Anyway, here's the proof.
Say $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Consider the following set: $A = \{f(x)\;|\;x\in[a,b]\}$. We know that this set is bounded by Theorem 2. Therefore, there exists a supremum (Theorem 3), $sup(A) = \alpha$. All we have to show is that $\alpha = f(x^*)$ where $x^*\in[a,b]$.
Suppose $\not\exists x^*\in[a,b]$ such that $\alpha = f(x^*)$. Then, for all $x\in[a,b]$, either $\alpha < f(x)$ or $\alpha > f(x)$. Let's say both possibilities occur. That is, let's suppose that $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $\alpha > f(x_0)$ and $x_1\in[a,b]$ such that $\alpha < f(x_1)$. So, $f(x_0) < \alpha < f(x_1)$. We know that this means that there exists an $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x) = \alpha$. However, in the beginning of this paragraph, we supposed that this isn't the case. Therefore, there is a contradiction.
Thus, if we're supposing that there does not exist an $x^*\in[a,b]$ such that $\alpha = f(x^*)$, we deduce that for all $x\in[a,b]$, $\alpha < f(x)$ or for all $x\in[a,b], \alpha > f(x)$. The first case clearly isn't true since that would make $\alpha$ a lower bound, not an upper bound. Now, the latter case. We already know that if $a > b$, there exists a $c$ such that $a - c > b$. We'll apply this knowledge. Since for all $x\in[a,b], \alpha > f(x)$, for each $x$, there must exist a $c_x$ such that $\alpha - c_x > f(x)$. Thus, $c_x < \alpha - f(x)$. We know that for all $x\in[a,b], f(x) < \alpha$. Thus, $c_x < \alpha$ if $f(x)\geq 0$. However, if $f(x) < 0$, then $c_x < \alpha + B$ where $f(x) > -B$.
Therefore, if we consider the set $\{c_x\;|\;x\in[a,b]\}$ we know that it is bounded. Thus, it has a supremum. Let $\beta$ be this supremum. So, $\forall x\in[a,b], f(x) < \alpha-\beta$. This is a contradiction since $\alpha-\beta$ is smaller than $\alpha$ and is also an upper bound.
Therefore, we deduce that $\exists x^*\in[a,b]$ such that $\alpha = f(x^*)$. QED
Is this correct?
Edit 1: As pointed out by @Especially Lime, I've rectified the sign error.

By definition of $A$ and $\sup$, we have $f(x)\le \alpha$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Thus you can drop the paragtraph where you investigate the possibility that $\alpha <f(x)$.

In my opinion the proof by contradiction is the simplest one, basing on Theorems $1$ and $2.$ If the supremum $M$ of the values of $f$ is not attained then the function $g(x)=(M- f(x))^{-1}$ is continuous, thus bounded above by say $a>0.$ Hence $f(x)\le M-a^{-1},$ a contradiction. Does it look unintuitive ?

No, it's not correct because of sign errors.
First from $\alpha-c_x>f(x)$ we get $c_x<\alpha-f(x)$, which is not obviously upper bounded by $2\alpha$ since $f(x)$ could be large and negative. But it is bounded by something since $f(x)$ is bounded below.
But more importantly, in the same way, if $\beta$ is the supremum of $\{c_x\mid x\in[a,b]\}$ then we get $\forall x\in[a,b], f(x)>\alpha-\beta$, and there's no way to deduce a contradiction from that.

In fact, this sort of approach can't possibly work because you are not actually using continuity. You are only using the properties that $f$ is bounded and satisfies the intermediate value theorem. There are functions (on a closed interval) with these properties that do not attain their bounds.

Thank you for responding. The sign error makes me feel stupid now. However, could you elaborate on why we get $f(x) > \alpha-\beta$? Since $\alpha - c_x  > f(x)$, once we show that $\beta$ is the maximum value $c_x$ can take, isn't it the case that $f(x) < \alpha-\beta$?

@Aryaan if you had $\alpha-c_x=f(x)$ and $c_x<\beta$, that gives $f(x)>\alpha-\beta$. Actually if you only know $\alpha-c_x>f(x)$, that's in the wrong direction to give you anything when combined with $c_x<\beta$. In order to get what you want, you'd need to take $\beta$ to be the infimum of $c_x$, but then all you would end up concluding is that the infimum is $0$.

There are a few problems with this approach. First, the use of Theorem 1 (the Intermediate Value Theorem) is superfluous: If $\alpha = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ and we suppose that, for all $x^* \in [a,b]$ we have $f(x^*) \neq \alpha$, then it follows immediately that $f(x)<\alpha$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ since by definition $\alpha$ is an upper bound for the set $\{f(x): x \in [a,b]\}$ so that $f(x)\leq \alpha$, $\forall x \in [a,b]$ and possibility of equality is ruled out by assumption.
Next, in trying to prove $\alpha$ is not the least upper bound, if I let $B$ be any set of real numbers with supremum $\alpha$, the argument as written applies to $B$, since it only uses the claim that if $a<b$ then there is a $c>0$ with $a<b-c$. But clearly if $B=[0,1)$ has supremum $1$ with $1 \notin B$.
As EspeciallyLime already noted, if $f(x)<\alpha$ then if you choose $c_x$ with $f(x)<\alpha-c_x$,then $c_x <\alpha-f(x)$, not $c_x < f(x)+\alpha$. Moreover, this will not give you any new information, because if $0< c_x < \alpha-f(x)$ for all $x \in [a.b]$ then $\inf_{x \in [a,b]} c_x =0$, and hence $f(x)<\alpha-c_x\leq \alpha-\inf_{x \in [a,b]} c_x = \alpha$.
I don't have Spivak with me at the moment, so I'm not sure which approach he takes, but there are two standard proofs of the fact that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f(x)$ attains a maximum value on $[a,b]$ assuming that one already knows $f$ must be bounded. The first essentially repeats the proof of boundedness, and the second uses a trick to reduce to the boundness statement.
Perhaps one of them satisfies your criterion of being intuitive?
In a little more detail: If $\alpha = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)<\infty$ then we can find, for each $n\in \mathbb N$, a point $x_n \in [a,b]$ with $\alpha-2^{-n} < f(x_n)\leq \alpha$. Now $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a bounded sequence, and hence has a convergent subsequence (by Bolzano-Weierstrass) $(x_{n_k})_{k \geq 1}$. Since $a\leq x_{n_k}\leq b$ for all $k \geq 1$ it follows that $l = \lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}\in [a,b]$ and since $|\alpha-f(x_{n_k})|<2^{-n_k} \leq 2^{-k}$ the continuity of $f$ implies that $f(l) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = \alpha$, so that $f$ attains its maximum value at $l$.
Alternatively, if $\alpha= \sup_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ and $\alpha$ is not a value of $f$ on $[a,b]$ then $g(x) = (\alpha-f(x))^{-1}$ is a continuous function defined on all of $[a,b]$ which, because $f$ takes values arbitrarily close to $\alpha$ must be unbounded on $[a,b]$, contradicting the boundedness of continuous functions on closed intervals.

Let $X = [a, b]$.
(1) There is no need to consider cases where $f (x) > \alpha$ for $x \in X$, because this would contradict the fact that $\alpha$ is the supremum of $\{f (x) | x \in X\}$. You only need to show a contradiction in the case where $f (x) < \alpha$ for each $x \in X$.
(2) Letting $\beta = \sup \{c_x | x \in X \}$ does not lead to a contradiction. You know that for each $x \in X$, $f (x) < \alpha - c_x$. But $c_x \le \beta = \sup \{ c_x | x \in X \}$, so you cannot conclude that $f (x) < \alpha - \beta$.
The key idea (and what is commonly used to show this theorem) is compactness of $X$. Continuous functions preserve compactness (show!), so the image $f (X)$ is compact. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $f (X)$ has no maximum. Then the collection $\{ (\leftarrow, y) | y \in f (X)\}$ constitutes an open cover of $f (X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Because $f (X)$ is compact, this collection contains a finite subcover $\{(\leftarrow, y_1), \dots, (\leftarrow, y_n)\}$. Being finite, the collection $\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$ has a maximum, say $y^* \in f (X)$. Note that $y^* \notin (\leftarrow, y_i)$ for any $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ because $y_i \le y^*$. This contradicts that $\{(\leftarrow, y_1), \dots, (\leftarrow, y_n)\}$ cover $f (X)$.
